# What is the behaviour of JDO/ORMs when doing a persist() on an object?

Tags: jpa, persistence, jdo

Here's my scenario (I'm using datanucleus, JDO, but I think it applies to JPA also):

```
tx.begin();
Dog d = new Dog();
persistenceManager.persist(d);
d.setName("Doggie");
tx.commit();
```

In the above code, the name "Doggie" is not persistent in the database.
However, when doing

```
tx.begin();
Dog d = new Dog();
d.setSize(10);
persistenceManager.persist(d);
Dog d2 = dogDao.getDogBySize(10);
d2.setName("Doggie");
tx.commit();
```

it works!

Is this behaviour due to the fact that my "second" dog is somehow a managed instance, being taken out of the database, while in the first example, the object is unmanaged?

Is it a behaviour JDO-specific?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just look at the log? It's there to help you after all ...

Answer (score 0):

In the above code indeed the update to the name is present in the datastore ... when I run it. And indeed when you look at the log you see a very clear INSERT for the persist and then an UPDATE, unless using optimistic txns when you get a single INSERT with the latest value of name.